# GDB bt error: "Not enough registers or memory available to unwind further"

Tags: c++, gdb, backtrace, debug-backtrace

The backtrace from core-file cut the useful information due to this:

> Backtrace stopped: Not enough registers or memory available to unwind
>   further.

Why this message occurs and can I do something about it?

Answer (score -2):

Try to build with -O0 flag

eg. CFLAGS="-g -O0"

Comment: Tried. Did not help!